# MongoDB version error while hosting on rander an Express App

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, hosting

I'm getting a Mongoose error with the Node version while hosting on Render.com

status showing: Exited with status 1 while building your code.

```
Jun 15 12:09:54 PM  ==> It looks like we don't have access to your repo, but we'll try to clone it anyway.
Jun 15 12:09:54 PM  ==> Cloning from https://github.com/yashkolte/New-Instagram...
Jun 15 12:09:56 PM  ==> Checking out commit e6b9470786f0cd5ab8d449315eb3201968d9cc4f in branch main
Jun 15 12:10:01 PM  ==> Using Node version 14.17.0 (default)
Jun 15 12:10:01 PM  ==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
Jun 15 12:10:01 PM  ==> Running build command 'yarn'...
Jun 15 12:10:01 PM  yarn install v1.22.5
Jun 15 12:10:01 PM  info No lockfile found.
Jun 15 12:10:01 PM  [1/4] Resolving packages...
Jun 15 12:10:08 PM  [2/4] Fetching packages...
Jun 15 12:10:13 PM  error mongoose@7.3.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.20.1". Got "14.17.0"
Jun 15 12:10:13 PM  error Found incompatible module.
Jun 15 12:10:13 PM  info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Jun 15 12:10:13 PM  ==> Build failed
```

What is the alternative of 'render' if the error can't be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found documentation on Specifying a Node Version on render.com

https://render.com/docs/node-version

add these lines in package.json

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.20.1"
  },
```

then commit and push to git,
deploy the latest commit on 'render'

The problem is now resolved

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of code in your package.json.

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">=NODE_JS_VERSION"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your package.json

`"engines": { "node": ">=14.20.1" }`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

I changed my node version to 18.17.0 instead render default version 14.17.0.

You can check this guide for more info. https://render.com/docs/node-version